# WordPress website redirect to cgi-sys/denied.shtml

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website when I try to open  domain.com/wp-admin .,it redirects to domin.com/cgi-sys/denied.shtml . But same is working fine on different network . I checked WordPress database as well, I don't have my IP  address in database.

what is the cause for this please help !

Thanks,
Digvijay

Comment: Delete cookies and cache?

Comment: Also, if the domain is new, then it might take up to ~24hrs for it to update it's domain pointer.

Comment: I have already cleared the cache. domain is old
it is not working on particular IP address, otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: What web server are you running (http server)? You should look through the access and error logs of this maybe, to see what happens there?